# mpdf with background color in TD tags through CSS

Tags: mpdf

I have an issue with regards to getting mpdf to generate table cells with Background Colors if the Color is specified in a CSS...
If the background color is specified in the css it is not displayed in the generated pdf, but if I specify it in the  as style is it displayed.
But for example the background color of the well (from the bootstrap css) is displayed correctly, there does not seem to be a general Problem with background-Color defined in the css...

Any idea, what could be causing this (and how to fix (besides putting all styles inline in the td tags) :-). I have also tried other html to pdf Solutions (dompdf, wkhtml2pdf) but the results were much worse.

In my CSS I have:

```
.bg-red {
    bgcolor: #ff0000;
}
```

In the PHP file I have:

```
 <?php 

$html = '<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print/print.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 </head>

<body>
    <div class="well">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr><td class="bg-red">Red Class (does not work)</td>
            <td style="background-color:#ff0000">Red inline style (does work)</td></tr>
        </table>
     <div class="bg-red">This also works</div>
    </div>  
</body>';


include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output(); 
exit;

?>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't

```
.bg-red {
    bgcolor: #ff0000;
}
```

be

```
.bg-red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```